# BigQuery connector ClassNotFoundException in PySpark on Dataproc

Tags: pyspark, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm trying to run a script in PySpark, using Dataproc.

The script is kind of a merge between [this example](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/bigquery-connector-spark-example) and what I need to do, as I wanted to check if everything works. Obviously, it doesn't.

The error I get is:

> File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
>   py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.newAPIHadoopRDD.
>   : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.JsonTextBigQueryInputFormat

I made sure I have all the jars, added some new jars as suggested in other similar posts. I also checked the `SPARK_HOME` variable.

Below you can see the code; the error appears when trying to instantiate table_data.

```py
"""BigQuery I/O PySpark example."""
from __future__ import absolute_import
import json
import pprint
import subprocess
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

sc = pyspark.SparkContext()

bucket = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().get('fs.gs.system.bucket')
project = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().get('fs.gs.project.id')
input_directory = 'gs://{}/hadoop/tmp/bigquery/pyspark_input'.format(bucket)

conf = {
    'mapred.bq.project.id': project,
    'mapred.bq.gcs.bucket': bucket,
    'mapred.bq.temp.gcs.path': input_directory,
    'mapred.bq.input.project.id': 'publicdata',
    'mapred.bq.input.dataset.id': 'samples',
    'mapred.bq.input.table.id': 'shakespeare',
}

output_dataset = 'wordcount_dataset'
output_table = 'wordcount_output'

table_data = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(
    'com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.JsonTextBigQueryInputFormat',
    'org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable',
    'com.google.gson.JsonObject',
    conf=conf)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the [example](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/bigquery-connector-spark-example), you need to include BigQuery connector jar when submitting the job.

Through Dataproc jobs API:

```sh
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark --cluster=${CLUSTER} \
    /path/to/your/script.py \
    --jars=gs://hadoop-lib/bigquery/bigquery-connector-hadoop2-latest.jar
```

or `spark-submit` from inside the cluster:

```sh
spark-submit --jars=gs://hadoop-lib/bigquery/bigquery-connector-hadoop2-latest.jar \
    /path/to/your/script.py
```