# error while loading data to bigquery table from dataproc cluster

Tags: apache-spark, google-bigquery, sbt, google-cloud-dataproc

I have a spark job that run in dataproc I want to load result to BigQuery, I know that I have to add spark-bigquery connector to save data to bigquery

```
  name := "spl_prj"

  version := "0.1"

  scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

  val sparkVersion = "2.3.0"

  conflictManager := ConflictManager.latestRevision

  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %%"spark-core" % sparkVersion % Provided,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % Provided ,
  "com.google.cloud.spark" %% "spark-bigquery-with-dependencies" % "0.17.3"
  )
```

when I build the jar and submit the job it gives this error:

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: bigquery. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:639)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:190)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:164)
at com.renault.datalake.spl_prj.Main$.main(Main.scala:58)
at com.renault.datalake.spl_prj.Main.main(Main.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:890)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:192)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:217)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:137)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bigquery.DefaultSource

I don't have the permission to add the jar when submitting the job lik in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56612930/bigquery-connector-classnotfoundexception-in-pyspark-on-dataproc)
I think that when sbt build the jar, does not add the connector in the compilation process, the snippest code scala spark that I want to run:

```
   val spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf).getOrCreate()
   val bucket = "doc_spk"
   spark.conf.set("temporaryGcsBucket", bucket)
   val sc =spark.sparkContext
   val rddRowString = sc.binaryRecords("gs://bucket/GAR", 120).map(x=>(x.slice(0,17),x.slice(17,20),x.slice(20,120)))
   val df=spark.createDataFrame(rddRowString).toDF("v","data","val_data")
   df.write.format("bigquery")
  .option("table","db.table")
  .save()
```

Comment: You have to build fat jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below `buil.sbt` file for building `fat` jar file.

**build.sbt**

```
name := "spl_prj"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.11.12"
val sparkVersion = "2.3.0"
conflictManager := ConflictManager.latestRevision

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %%"spark-core" % sparkVersion % Provided,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % Provided ,
  "com.google.cloud.spark" %% "spark-bigquery-with-dependencies" % "0.17.3"
)
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF","services",xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.filterDistinctLines
  case PathList("META-INF",xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case _ => MergeStrategy.first
}

assemblyOption in assembly := (assemblyOption in assembly).value.copy(includeScala = false)
assemblyJarName in assembly := s"${name.value}-${version.value}.jar"
```

Create `project/plugins.sbt` file & add below content.

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.15.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-buildinfo" % "0.9.0")
```

Run below command to create ```fat`` jar.

```
sbt clean compile assembly
```

**Note** : You can adjust versions as per your project requirements.